# My Google Analytics setup for hugo is not working

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-hosting, hugo, google-analytics-4

I've added my tracking id to my config.toml and everything looks like its matching up. Yet I haven’t seen any realtime data come in when I launch https://analytics.google.com/

```
theme = "osprey-delight"
tags = ["personal", "homepage", "portfolio"]
# canonifyURLS = true
googleAnalytics = "G-SYJ123456"
disableKinds = ["taxonomy", "taxonomyTerm"] # This theme does not currently use "tag" and "category" taxonomies
enableEmoji = true
pygmentsUseClasses = true
```

I'm using a theme(osprey-delight) and in the layouts/partials directory, theres a head.html that contains template string, will paste below:

```
  {{ if .Site.GoogleAnalytics }}
    {{ template "_internal/google_analytics_async.html" . }}
  {{ end }}
```

When i deploy to firebase, i do see a script tag for ga in my main index.html file in /public directory, here it is below -

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var doNotTrack = false;
if (!doNotTrack) {
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'G-12345689', 'auto');
    
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
```

What am I missing? I feel like I've don't everything right, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update February 2020**

Below you can find the solution with Universal Analytics, alternatively you can try implementing the solution for Hugo to send data to your **GA4** data stream: https://gist.github.com/zjeaton/42246742cdaf2fb46400d04c2eba9a8a#file-analytics-gtag-html

---

**Solution with Universal Analytics**

I suggest you create a Universal Analytics Property (as shown in following image) and use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X (easy way):

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to use GA4 Property you have to follow relative syntax:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4

Comment: so i'd add the UA key in my config file?

Comment: Do you have to select this option during property setup or can you add this after the fact?  I'm not seeing it in property settings.

Comment: You can find it when you create a new property

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a Universal Analytics Property, you can implement the solution for Hugo as proposed by Zachary Eaton and keep your GA4 property: https://gist.github.com/zjeaton/42246742cdaf2fb46400d04c2eba9a8a#file-analytics-gtag-html